# $inject Annotation on angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I've see that [Angular Seed](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed) comes with $inject annotation on Controllers reference, which means that I can declare the dependencies for the controller with that.

The [DI documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) shows that the constructor need to be in sync with current arguments os Controller.

Also, in [this documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05), it was shows one use of this annotation, usefull on minified JS sources. Like this:

```
var MyController = function(renamed$scope, renamedGreeter) {
  ...
}
MyController.$inject = ['$scope', 'greeter'];
```

where I found an explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14361692/why-doesnt-appctrl-have-inject-but-myctrl1-does-in-this-angularjs-example).

So, my doubt is:

1. There is another use for this annotation?
2. On non-minified JS sources, is there any advantage or disadvantage to not use it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you clarify 2nd point

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see that was the same as first point. Removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purpose of $inject is to ensure your dependencies are injected properly if your code is minified.

There are three ways to manage dependencies in AngularJS - [DI in AngularJS](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.managing_dependencies)

Array Notation is my preferred approach as it is simpler than the $inject approach.

To answer your specific questions:

1. No, I am not aware of another use for $inject.
2. If you don't use one of the first two approaches mentioned in the linked article, your code will not function if someone minifies the source.  The array notation is simple and it makes your code compatible with minifiers, so I don't know why you wouldn't use it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.
Some things are gradually becoming clearer to me.

Comment: Mark Sherretta did you know if Google Closure Compiler works fine to angular? http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home