# Are the square brackets in angular still required?

Tags: angularjs

I know they're used for keeping track of minified variables, but I've noticed a lot of examples that exclude them.

I'm not a big fan of all that boilerplate, so if they are required, what are some clean ways to use them -- without some big long line of strings.

Comment: You can use $inject or even ng-annotate

Comment: Can you show an example?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16149616/inject-annotation-on-angularjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No they aren't at all. You can use ng-annotate you insert them for you pre-minification.

https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate

https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-ng-annotate